# Transfer learning with Keras for medical image classification

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, transfer-learning

I'm trying to do Transfer Learning from a pre-trained model on imagenet to solve a classification task with Lung CT slices.
These slices are stored in `dicom` file, so their value is expressed on 12 bits in the Hounsfield scale. My questions are: `preprocess_input` of Keras / tf2 API needs a matrix of values in [0,255], so how can I preprocess my images to fed them to a pre-trained convnet? Can I to normalize the range of the image in [0,1] or it's mandatory to use `preprocess_input` of models? If `preprocess_input` is mandatory, how can I map the 12-bit value in the range [0,255]?